# Print keyboard shortcuts for jupyter notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook

After I open a notebook, I can press H or P to see a pop up window showing a list of keyboard shortcuts. With P, I get a search box in the popup. How do I print any one of them? With Ctrl+P, I get to print the notebook, not the shortcuts.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Copy and paste into a word processor (Word, for example) - then print that document.

Comment: kindly consider adding more information in your answer